# sql to show two addresses

Tags: sql, sql-server

If a person has got two addresses then I need post a letter for both the addresses otherwise post to the letter to the family address which is one.

```
SELECT id, firstname, lastname, address, postcode, email
From constituent
```

The data I have is as below:

```
10001,Esther,Wheels,101 Rosehill, WA1878,sue.w@hotmail.com
10001,Esther,wheels,30 miles rd, 123UDF,hws.isthe@hotmail.com
10001,Esther,Wheels,101 Rosehill, WA1878,
```

How to put this information in a single row showing
id,firstname,lastname, address1,postcode1,address2,postcode2,email1,email2,First

Family(flag), Second family(x)? If there is no second address it should show just one address.

Please help?

Comment: What if there are more than two addresses?  If you are using SQL Server, the appropriate tag is "sql-server".

Comment: Please show the expected output for the sample data you provided.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, if there are three address then it should all the three addresses , but if not atleast two should pop up as a second family

Comment: @kurtkline 10001,Esthefr,Wheels,101 Rosehill,WA1878,30 miles rd,123UDF,sue.w@hotmail.com,hws.isthe@hotmail.com,x,x.

Comment: You want to do a [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot). Because your number of columns depends on your data, you will need a "dynamic pivot" (pivot + dynamics SQL) like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688697/mssql-dynamic-pivot-column-values-to-column-header).

Comment: Why do you have the same name three times? If they are the same person, there should be a `Person` table, and an `Address` table which references it

Comment: Doing this in SQL will probably be ugly and unmaintainable. IMHO better to pull all addresses with one query and let the code getting the addresses handle putting it into a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Please check is below solution suitable for you:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  lastname,
  STRING_AGG(CONCAT(address, ',', postcode), ',') address,
  STRING_AGG(email, ',') email
FROM 
  constituent
GROUP BY id, lastname;
```

[MSSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=8b77ac29830e37a48879b16ebba1efd6&php_version=null&sql_version=mssql2017)

Result:

```
+=======+==========+============================================================+==========================================+
| id    | lastname | address                                                    | email                                    |
+=======+==========+============================================================+==========================================+
| 10001 | Wheels   | 101 Rosehill,WA1878,30 miles rd,123UDF,101 Rosehill,WA1878 | sue.w@hotmail.com,hws.isthe@hotmail.com, |
+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: but i want the address in separate columns