# SQL - get all parents/childs?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

hopefully someone can help with this. I have recieved a table of data which I need to restructure and build a Denorm table out of. The table structure is as follows

```
UserID     Logon    ParentID 
2344       Test1     2000
2345       Test2     2000
```

The issue I have is the ParentID is also a UserID of its own and in the same table.

SELECT * FROM tbl where ParentID=2000 gives the below output

```
UserID     Logon      ParentID 
2000       Test Team     2500
```

Again, the ParentID of this is also stored as a UserID..

SELECT * FROM tbl where ParentID=2500 gives the below output

```
UserID     Logon            ParentID 
2500       Test Division     NULL
```

I want a query that will pull all of these relationships and the logons into one row, with my output looking like the below.

```
 UserID   Username       Parent1        Parent2        Parent3     Parent4
 2344       Test1      Test Team      Test Division    NULL         NULL
 2345       Test2      Test Team      Test Division    NULL         NULL
```

The maximum number of parents a user can have is 4, in this case there is only 2. Can someone help me with the query needed to build this?

Appreciate any help
Thanks
Jess

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and why its not working.

Comment: One solution I found had the parents and childIDs on separate table which isn't the case here. i wouldn't know where to start with the above as I am not too advanced

Comment: Have a look at recursive cte. An application is in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959804/simulation-of-connect-by-prior-of-oracle-in-sql-server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use basicly LEFT JOIN. If you have static 4 parent it should work. If you have unknown parents you should do dynamic query.

```
SELECT U1.UserId
        ,U1.UserName
        ,U2.UserName AS Parent1
        ,U3.UserName AS Parent2
        ,U4.UserName AS Parent3
        ,U5.UserName AS Parent4
FROM Users U1
LEFT JOIN Users U2 ON U1.ParentId = U2.UserId
LEFT JOIN Users U3 ON U2.ParentId = U3.UserId
LEFT JOIN Users U4 ON U3.ParentId = U4.UserId
LEFT JOIN Users U5 ON U4.ParentId = U5.UserId
```

**EDIT** : Additional(to exclude parent users from the list) :

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Users UC WHERE U1.UserId = UC.ParentId)
```

Comment: This works but I get some rows where the Username is the parent1. For example I am seeing "Test Team" as a username with Test Division as parent 1. Is there anyway to exclude these?

Comment: @Jess8766 if you only want rows for users that are not parents you need to add WHERE U1.UserId NOT IN (SELECT ParentId FROM Users)

Comment: @Jess8766 I have added NOT EXISTS condition to the WHERE statement to exclude parent users.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   tb1.UserId as UserId,
   tb1.UserName as UserName,
   tb2.UserName as Parent1, 
   tb3.UserName as Parent2, 
   tb4.UserName as Parent3, 
   tb5.UserName as Parent4 
from tbl t1 
left join tbl t2 on t2.UserId=t1.ParentID 
left join tbl t3 on t3.UserId=t2.ParentID 
left join tbl t4 on t4.UserId=t3.ParentID  
left join tbl t5 on t5.UserId=t4.ParentID;
```

you need to do 4 left joins in order to fetch 4 parent details

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all parent or child, it's efficient to use a recursive function which would fetch the whole hierarchy.

Sample Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
[Name] varchar(100),
ManagerName Varchar(100),
Number int
)
```

Insert some values

```
Insert into Test values
('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('c','d'), ('d','e'), ('e','f'), ('f','g')
```

Create recursive function as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnRecursive] (@EmpName Varchar(100), @incremental int)
RETURNS @ret TABLE 
(

 ManagerName varchar(100),
 Number int
)
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @MgrName varchar(100)

  SET @MgrName = (Select ManagerName from test where [name] = @EmpName)

  Insert into @ret values (@MgrName, @incremental)
  if(@MgrName is not null)
  BEGIN
     SET @incremental = @incremental + 1;
     Insert into @ret
     Select ManagerName, Number  from [fnRecursive](@MgrName, @incremental)

  END

   RETURN;
END
```

If this function is joined with table, it should list the hierarchy for all employees

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST
(
  [Name] varchar(100),
  ManagerName Varchar(100),
  Number int
)



 Insert into #TEST
 Select x.[Name], x.ManagerName,x.number from (
 select t.[Name],a.ManagerName as managerName, a.number as number  from TEST t outer apply
 (
    select * from [fnRecursive](t.[Name],1)
 ) a)
 x

Select * from #Test
```

If we do a pivot on the table (excluding the 'Number' column). Assuming we store in the table "#temp"  it should list all the managers as a column.

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
 @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[ManagerName] ) 
        FROM #temp c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')



  set @query = 'select * from #temp
        pivot 
        (
            min([managername])
            for managername in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

  execute(@query)
```

But this doesn't name the column as 'Parent1', 'Parent2' instead with the dynamic column name.

Link below should help to set custom column name for the dynamic pivot table

```
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614994/sql-server-pivot-with-custom-column-names
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive CTE to get the levels then pivot to put them in columns:

```
WITH cte(UserID, Logon, ParentID, ParentLogon, ParentLevel) AS
(
  SELECT UserID, Logon, ParentID, Logon,  0
  FROM users
  UNION ALL
  SELECT u.UserID, u.Logon, u.ParentID, cte.ParentLogon, ParentLevel + 1
  FROM users u
  JOIN cte ON cte.UserID = u.ParentID
)
SELECT UserId, Logon, Parent1, Parent2, Parent3, Parent4 FROM cte
PIVOT (
  MAX(ParentLogon)
  FOR ParentLevel
  IN (
    1 AS Parent1,
    2 AS Parent2,
    3 AS Parent3,
    4 AS Parent4
  )
)
```

See [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/942d6/56)