# How do I select all employees and display them in rows per department?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, self-join

Below is an example of the data I want to manipulate in my select statement.

```
Employee ID | Department ID  |  FirstName  |  LastName  |  Role
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   1            |  Jack       | Skeleton   | Cashier
2           |   2            |  Rachel     | Sparrow    | Cashier
3           |   1            |  Samuel     | Kite       | Bagger
4           |   2            |  Arnold     | Herrera    | Bagger
5           |   1            |  Edwin      | Molina     | Bagger
```

Below is how I want to display my data.

```
Dept ID| Emp ID  |  Role  |  Emp ID  |  Role  | EmpID  |  Role  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1       |Cashier | 3        |Bagger  | 5      |  Bagger|
2      | 2       |Cashier | 4        |Bagger  |
```

I have tried a Pivot, but selecting the same columns for each employee in the same row has been an issue for me.

Also I wanted to note that each department has a different number of employees. So, some rows would show 6 employees for that department and others would display 4 or 9

Comment: If you don't know how many columns you need, then you need a dynamic pivot.  This may be easier to accomplish in the presentation layer.

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS If you don't write a clear description of what you want then you can't search for it & or ask for it & how do you hope to program it?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. We only have an example so we can only guess what that is. Dumps of requirements are not on-topic questions. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show what relevant parts you can do & explain re the first place you are stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : Pivot with custom column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16614994/3404097)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you're looking for.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
GO 
--================================================================
-- create some test data...

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Department', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #Department; END;

CREATE TABLE #Department (
    DepartmentID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Department (DepartmentID, DepartmentName) VALUES
    (1, 'Department 1'), (2, 'Department 2');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employee', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #Employee; END;

CREATE TABLE #Employee (
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DepartmentID INT NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    [Role] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #Employee (EmployeeID, DepartmentID, FirstName, LastName, [Role]) VALUES

    (1, 1, 'Jack', 'Skeleton', 'Cashier'),
    (2, 2, 'Rachel', 'Sparrow', 'Cashier'),
    (3, 1, 'Samuel', 'Kite', 'Bagger'),
    (4, 2, 'Arnold', 'Herrera', 'Bagger'),
    (5, 1, 'Edwin', 'Molina', 'Bagger');

--================================================================
-- begin the actual solution...

DECLARE 
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'',
    @debug BIT = 0;    -- choose 0 the execute the dynamic sql & 1 to print it.

WITH
    cte_columns_needed AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.DepartmentID ORDER BY e.EmployeeID)
        FROM
            #Employee e
        )    
SELECT TOP (10000)
    @sql = CONCAT(@sql, N',
    ', QUOTENAME(N'EmpID_' + x.rn), N' = MAX(CASE WHEN ern.rn = ', cn.rn, N' THEN ern.EmployeeID END),
    ', QUOTENAME(N'Role_' + x.rn), N' = MAX(CASE WHEN ern.rn = ', cn.rn, N' THEN ern.Role END)'
    )
FROM
    cte_columns_needed cn
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cn.rn)) ) x (rn)
ORDER BY
    cn.rn;

SET @sql = CONCAT(N'
SELECT 
    [DeptID] = ern.DepartmentID',
    @sql, N'
FROM (
    SELECT 
        e.EmployeeID,
        e.DepartmentID,
        e.Role,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.DepartmentID ORDER BY e.EmployeeID)
    FROM
        #Employee e
    ) ern
GROUP BY
    ern.DepartmentID
ORDER BY
    ern.DepartmentID;'
);

IF @debug = 1
BEGIN 
    PRINT(@sql);
END;
ELSE 
BEGIN
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

Note... This type of dynamic code isn't exactly intuitive for most people. So, please feel free to ask whatever questions come up.

Comment: I apologize for not getting back to you sooner but this did the trick. I struggled a long time trying to find an answer. Thank you.  I do have questions though I tried doing it with something much much bigger and my @sql nvarchar(max) is too small for the whole query. Any ideas on how to make the variable bigger?

Comment: @Jovany - the nvarchar(max) data type can hold up to two gigs of Unicode text. If you're outrunning that, something is WAY off.  I suspect that you've simply exceeded the 8000K limit of of the PRINT() command... Are you seeing the problem with debug = 1 or debug = 0?

Comment: I edited the final bit of code to just print the sql variable because I wanted to see the query and verify it before it actually ran. Running it with the debugs in place I get multiple errors listing all my column names are invalid. Should I create a new post for this issue or is there another way to share with you the code I am working with now.